# Mysql SELECT COUNT(*) OR SELECT 1? PDO

Tags: php, mysql, count, pdo

It has long been known that PDO does not support COUNT(*) and a query like below would fail as it doesn't return any affected rows,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($id));
echo $q -> rowCount();
```

Doing some research I found that you can also get the row count using other methods of count and not using count at all, for example the following query is supposed be the same as above but will return correct for PDO,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($id));
echo $q -> rowCount();
```

There are various sources on the internet claiming that;

```
"SELECT COUNT(*)
"SELECT COUNT(col)
"SELECT 1
```

Are all the same as each other (with a few differences) so how come using mysql which PDO cannot properly return a true count, does

```
"SELECT 1
```

work?

**Methods of count discussion**

[Why is Select 1 faster than Select count(*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406099/why-is-select-1-faster-than-select-count)

Comment: `SELECT 1` will only return a value of 1 for that column - the other options count not null values.  I think you meant to write `COUNT(1)`

Comment: @OMG: Unless the OP is only doing an existence check, and then `select exists(select 1 ...` would be the my choice.

Comment: The SO question you refer to is for a different database -- there are duplicates of this which are currently escaping me but this is close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697137/countid-vs-count-in-mysql

Comment: `id` is the primary key, right? Otherwise the two queries will have vastly different results.

Comment: @mu is too short: Agreed

Comment: Actually I think `echo $q -> rowCount();` does work with `SELECT 1`.  You don't want the `rowCount()` call with `SELECT COUNT(*)` though; you want the value returned.

Comment: @RayToal Yes it does work and it is baffling me to why it does?!?

Comment: Well, according to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) `rowCount` might work for SELECT statements -- it is just not guaranteed -- so maybe you got lucky?

Comment: I am running a few tests now with other queries to see how they return, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Check my answer, that's all the code you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> PDO does not support COUNT(*)

WTF? Of course PDO supports `COUNT(*)`, you are using it the wrong way.

```
$q = $dbc->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) as records FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$q->execute(array($id));    
$records = (int) $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->records;
```

If you are using a driver other than MySQL, you might have to test `rowCount` first, like this.

```
$records = (int) ($q->rowCount()) ? $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->records : 0;
```

Comment: there is no use for the rowcount here. you will get your 0 without it.

Comment: I use it because i've experience erratic behavior on different drivers, if i remember correctly, Postgre will return 0 on `rowCount`. 

If you are using MySQL, you can be safe using just: `$records = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->records;`.

Answer (score 6):

Oh. You are confusing everything.

1. PDO do not interfere with SQL queries. It support EVERYTHING supported by SQL.
2. When doing `COUNT(*)` you shouldn't use rowcount at all, as it just makes no sense. You have to retreive the query result instead.
3. Dunno what "various sources" you are talking about but `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(col)` (and even `COUNT(1)`) are the same and **the only proper way to get count** of records when you need no records themselves.

COUNT is an aggregate function, *it counts rows for you*. So, it returns the result already, no more counting required. Ad it returns just a scalar value in the single row. Thus, using `rowcount` on this single row makes no sense

`SELECT 1` is not the same as above, as it selects just literal `1` **for the every row found in the table**. So, it will return a thousand `1s` if there is a thousands rows in your database. So, rowcount will give you the result but it is going to be an extreme waste of the server resources.

there is a simple rule to follow:

## Always request the only data you need.

If you need the count of rows - request count of rows. Not a thousand of 1s to count them later.
Sounds sensible?

Comment: And PDO does not support COUNT so how come when I use SELECT 1 it returns the COUNT, not confusing just a simple question.

Comment: When you `SELECT 1 FROM x` and then take the row count you will return a count of rows of `x`, because you're saying "From X, for each row give me 1". So you get 10,000 1's in return.

Comment: PDO does support COUNT. I use it all the time.

Comment: @NovacTownCode added a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I think to test if a line exist in your database is to perform.

```
SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1
```

If it find a row it will stop and tell you there is a line. If it don't and you have an index on your where clause column it will also goes very fast to see there are none available.