# SQLAlchemy Select with Exist limiting

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with 4 columns (1 PK) from which I need to select 30 rows.
Of these rows, two columns (col. A and B) must exists in another table (8 columns, 1 PK, 2 are A and B).

Second table is large, contains millions of records and it's enough for me to know if even a single row exists containing values of col. A and B of 1st table.

I am using the code below:

```
query = db.Session.query(db.Table_1).\
        filter(
            exists().where(db.Table_2.col_a == db.Table_1.col_a).\
                     where(db.Table_2.col_b == db.Table_2.col_b)
        ).limit(30).all()
```

This query gets me the results I desire however I'm afraid it might be a bit slow since it does not imply `a limit` condition to `exists()` function nor does it do `select 1` but a `select *`.

```
exists() does not accept a .limit(1)
```

How can I put a limit to exists to get it not to look for whole table, hence making this query run faster?

- I need n rows from **Table_1**, which **2 columns exist in a record** in
  **Table_2**

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the "select 1" thing using a more explicit form as it mentioned [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html?highlight=exists#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists), that is,

```
exists([1]).where(...)
```

However, while I've been a longtime diehard "select 1" kind of guy, I've since learned that the usage of "1" vs. "*" for performance is now [a myth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406497/34549) ([more](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?28741.html) / [more](http://justoracle.blogspot.com/2006/12/count-vs-count1.html)).

exists() is also a wrapper around select(), so you can get a limit() by constructing the select() first:

```
s = select([1]).where(
         table1.c.col_a == table2.c.colb
       ).where(
         table1.c.colb == table2.c.colb
       ).limit(30)
s = exists(s)
```

Comment: Hey, this is excellent! Thank you very much @zzzeek. In fact, this is fantastic! ;-))

Comment: One thing to note: to execute `s`, you need to generate a select for it: `conn.execute(s.select())`.

Answer (score -1):

```
query=select([db.Table_1])
query=query.where(
     and_(
           db.Table_2.col_a == db.Table_1.col_a,
           db.Table_2.col_b == db.Table_2.col_b
          )
     ).limit(30)

result=session.execute(query)
```